# Error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid argument.'

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm programming a c# application that I want to connect to a list on a sharepoint website. The web address is https://mmae.sharepoint.com/sites/MMAEDB. The list I'm trying to connect to is called Board. The web address of the List name, description and navigation settings is https://mmae.sharepoint.com/sites/MMAEDB/_layouts/15/ListGeneralSettings.aspx?List=%7B8D06EFD1-76E1-4DE6-B8AC-A13CF507752C%7D.
This is my connection string located in my form load

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        con2 = new OleDbConnection("Provider = 
      Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=2;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE = 
      https://mmae.sharepoint.com/; LIST = {8D06EFD1-76E1-4DE6-B8AC-
      A13CF507752C};");


        con2.Open();

    }
```

When I attempt to run my code I get an error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Invalid argument.'

Comment: a single line. It was too long to fit on one line in the question box.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: con2.open();does